# Remove "Get smart with the Thesis Wordpress Theme" on wordpress footer

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

Been spending a couple of hours trying to remove this texts on the footer "Get smart with the Thesis" on my wordpress site. I used thesis theme. I've tried looking for the footer file containing the texts but no luck. I also tried removing it from the hooks. "custom_functions.php" but still doesn't work. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: are u sure you are not seeing the cached version of the pages? just an idea.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/decrypt.php

Comment: Is that line supposed to be left in per the terms of the theme licence...?

Comment: @Martin: i don't think because it isn't a free theme: http://diythemes.com/plans/

Comment: @Sabeen: I'm pretty sure it is not a cached version. I always cleared up my cache to make sure I get the latest view.

Comment: @Martin: I did purchased the theme.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20101227142322/http://www.bloghighlight.com/best-way-to-remove-footer-link-in-thesis-theme/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help

http://www.sugarrae.com/thesis-hooks-dummies-tutorial/#change-footer

```
/* Custom Footer Hook */
remove_action('thesis_hook_footer', 'thesis_attribution');
function add_custom_footer () {
?>
<p>© 2008 Ourblog.com – All rights reserved. – <a href="http://www.ourblog.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></p>
<p>No content on this site may be reused in any fashion without written permission from Ourblog.com or whatever you want your footer to include</p>
<?php
}
add_action('thesis_hook_footer', 'add_custom_footer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following directory:

```
\wordpress_root\wp-content\themes\your_theme_name
```

In this folder is a file called `footer.php`

In this file you will find the text you want to remove.

SORRY Did not see that you did this already:

without downloading the theme I am not sure. Please post the footer.php file so we can help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
This doesn't work either. The text is not in the footer.php.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. You can use Thesis Hooks to do that.

```
remove_action('thesis_hook_footer', 'thesis_attribution');
```

Read More here

Answer (score 0):

For thesis 1.x version you have to add a code to remove it from the footer.
But for the latest thesis 2 version you can drag and delete that footer attribution box using the skin editor option of the thesis 2 version. For more info refer to these posts

- For thesis 2.x  :[Remove thesis attribution link from Thesis 2 footer](http://www.mytechshout.com/remove-thesis-attribution-link-from-footer-in-thesis-2.html)
- For thesis 1.x [Remove thesis footer link for thesis theme 1.8](http://www.mytechshout.com/how-remove-thesis-thesis-attribution-footer-link-add-your-own-site-link-thesis-theme.html)

Hope this will be helpful.